# How to detect flash and prompt to install?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, flash

If no flash is installed and one browses to http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php it'll launch a popup box:

[image]

How exactly are they doing this? Through some jQuery java-script code snippet or other?

Second, I would like to know if there is a better way to inform the user that they need flash. Or is this an appropriate way?

Comment: If you go to Adobe's site and search there, they have all this information documented there.

Comment: @Christian Fazzini - Hey bro ... I am facing same issue...did you got the trick to prompt  or launch above popup to ask client to install flash ?

Comment: @Prog Can't remember now. I believe we were trying to implement user uploads via flash. In the end, we were quite happy with using filepicker.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check-out SWFObject, it has a utility for checking the current version of Flash installed and if it isn't new enough or not available at all it can prompt the user to install: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Also if you search Google for `detect flash version javascript` you will get some other packages/plugins that do the same type of detection.

Comment: At http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation it mentions, `swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.115", "expressInstall.swf");`. However, at http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php In the source, I don't see any code that is similar. What exact method / approach are they using to detect and download flash?

Comment: That site is using Yahoo's BrowserPlus: http://browserplus.org. I'm not familiar with the product but I think it's what you're looking for.