# How to detect flash and prompt to install with plupload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, plupload

If no flash is installed and one browses to http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php it'll launch a popup box prompting the user to download Adobe Flash.

I did some reading at http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation which suggests doing something like:

```
swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.115", "expressInstall.swf");
```

Fair enough, however I realize that plupload assigns random id's for its flash object every time the page is refreshed. Which makes it impossible to determine the id for swfobject. For example:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" style="outline:0" data="/flash/plupload/plupload.flash.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="p16ko0lvqt1ad01ovuh441kal1cc40_flash">...</object>
```

Notice the

```
p16ko0lvqt1ad01ovuh441kal1cc40_flash
```

above?

Am I on the right track here, or should I take a different approach? Your thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068190/how-to-detect-flash-and-prompt-to-install

Comment: This one is specific to plupload alone